# Rails 3.2.6 - Running rake assets:precompile and getting an error with form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I try to run a rake assets:precompile I keep getting this error:

```
rake aborted!
/new-ui/app/views/account_assets/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ')'
_erbout = ''; _erbout.concat(( form_for @asset do |f| ).to_s)
```

The code it is referencing is a very simple partial as such:

```
<%= form_for @asset do |f| %>
<% if @asset.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@asset.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this asset from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @asset.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :account_id %><br />
 <%= f.number_field :account_id %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :asset_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :asset_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :asset_location %><br />
<%= f.text_field :asset_location %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I've seen other posts on stack overflow that say to remove the = sign from the form_for but when I do that I get an error that the method form_for not found, so I don't think that is the way to go.

Anyone have any idea?  Thanks

**UPDATE**
Here is the full trace:

```
rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
SMTP configuration:
   SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com
   SMTP port:   587
   SMTP domain: testmymail.com
   SMTP auth:   plain
   SMTP user:   noreply@testmymail.com
ActiveMerchant gateway: paypal
           login: seller.testmymail.com
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
/home/dan/Clients/Boomerang/new-ui/app/views/account_assets/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ')'
_erbout = ''; _erbout.concat(( form_for @asset do |f| ).to_s)
                                                       ^
/home/dan/Clients/Boomerang/new-ui/app/views/account_assets/_form.html.erb:32: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
/home/dan/Clients/Boomerang/new-ui/app/views/account_assets/_form.html.erb:34: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
  (in /home/dan/Clients/Boomerang/new-ui/app/views/account_assets/_form.html.erb)
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:209:in `instance_eval'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:209:in `evaluate_source'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:144:in `cached_evaluate'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:127:in `evaluate'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:177:in `block in evaluate'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `each'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `evaluate'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `new'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `block in build_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:262:in `circular_call_protection'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:240:in `build_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `new'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `build_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:23:in `block in compile'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/...]
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@boomerang/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: Please include stacktrace of error. Asset precompilation should NOT be requiring the view. If it is requiring the view, then something is very, very wrong.

Comment: I just added the trace output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like some component registered `account_assets/_form.html.erb` to compile by [tilt engine](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/blob/master/TEMPLATES.md).

Try to switch off initialization of app with `assets:precompile`.
Inside `config/application.rb` add this: (but [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) for warnings about it)

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Do you have any modifications related to assets in `config/application.rb` or `config/enviroment/production.rb` or `config/environments/development.rb`?